# How to prevent a UIPageViewController's setViewControllers method from crashing?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get a UIPageViewController to work for the first time, but I seem to be having trouble whenever I attempt to set its view controllers.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let leftViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController")
    let rightViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController")

    let viewControllerArray: [UIViewController] = [leftViewController!, rightViewController!]

    self.setViewControllers(viewControllerArray, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Every time I reach the `setViewControllers()` method, the app crashes in the `AppDelegate` file with the following error log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'The number of view controllers provided (2) doesn't match the number 
required (1) for the requested transition

23  UIKit                               0x0000000103a06610 UIApplicationMain + 171
24  PageViewTesting                     0x000000010300649d main + 109
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105a3292d start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I currently have one `UIPageViewController` and two `UIViewControllers` within my storyboard. I've double checked that their IDs are correct as well for the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` methods.

Any ideas to why I'm receiving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the class reference from `UIPageViewController`:

```
// setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:
func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?,
          direction direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection,
           animated animated: Bool,
         completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

> The view controllers passed to this method are those that will be
>   visible after the animation has completed. **Use a data source to
>   provide additional view controllers to which users navigate**.

For single view controller view mode, the method `.setViewControllers` used in your code takes only a single view controller (however, on array form). It's a bit confusing that the argument takes an array `[UIViewController]`, but this is for using the `doubleSided` property for the PageViewController, when using a spine (mid) view.

> When defining a page view controller interface, you can provide the
>   content view controllers one at a time (or two at a time, depending
>   upon the spine position and double-sided state)
>
> ...
>
> `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid`
>
> Spine in the middle or the
>   screen.
>
> Two view controllers are displayed at a time.

Are you intending to use a spine mid view? In that case, you can sen two view controllers, otherwise, you should just send one and add others using a data source.

Comment: Unfortunately that code won't work. XCode errors out during the downcast to `UIViewController` as using the instantiation method already provides an `UIViewController` element. Also, the `self.setViewControllers()` method requires that the `UIViewController` array is strictly that, it won't accept an optional array.

Comment: I messed up my first answer, try the edited version above (or did you indeed try the edited version?)

Comment: I tried both, still getting that dang error unfortunately.

Comment: It only occurs once `self.setViewControllers(viewControllerArray, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)` is called upon, but why, I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, then, could you possible update your question with also the top of the error message (not just lines 23-26). Should be above "*** First throw call stack:" or at least above "1" entry.

Comment: Just updated with the error message, thanks for that, didn't even know there was a descriptive error message up top.

Comment: Ah there it is. 1 sec

Comment: Looks like it only takes one view controller and I have to add others using a data source?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You can send two if you use a spine view, but for separate view controllers, you need to send only one view controller and rest as a data source.

Comment: Sweet, thanks a ton @dfri, I've been looking for a good tutorial on page view controllers, but unfortunately most of the ones I've seen for Swift just go over the implementation without much explanation. Thinking I might make one myself once I get mine working correctly.

Comment: You're welcome! I agree that for storyboard/segues and so on, it's usually trial by error (and lots of errors..) that is the most accessible way to learn as tutorials focus mostly on code and implementation. Possible have a look at Stanfords Swift (1.2) course with Paul Hegarty though, he covers quite a lot of storyboard/segue related stuff. Happy coding!

Comment: I've actually gone through the first two lessons of that course, Paul's a great teacher, really helped me understand what good, dry code looks like. Happy coding to you as well, looking forward to seeing the awesome stuff we can create in this world.